# modified activity selection

Tags: dynamic-programming, greedy

in activity selection we sort on finish time of activities and then apply the constraint that no two activities can overlap.i want to know whether can we do it by sorting on start time andthenseeing if activities do not overlap

i was going through http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-20-maximum-length-chain-of-pairs/

this link has a dynamic programming solution for finding maximum length chain of pairs of numbers .. this according to me is another formulation of activity selection problem but i have searched on net and as also have read cormen but everywhere they ask to sort on finish times ...
i guess it shouldnt matter on what times(start or finish)we sort but just want to confirm the same

Answer (score 1):

In greedy algorithm we always try to maximize our result. Thus, In activity selection we try to accommodate as many processes as we can in a given time interval without overlapping each other.

If you sort on start time then your solution might not be an optimal solution. Let's take an example,

```
Processes        start Time      Finish Time 
A                  1                9
B                  3                5
C                  6                8
```

Sorted on start Time:
If you execute process A because it starts at the earliest no other process can be executed because they will overlap. Therefore, for a given time interval you can only execute one process.

Sorted on Finish Time:
If you execute process B because it ends at the earliest you can execute process C after that. Therefore, for a given time interval you can execute two processes.